# Documentary with the actors from e.g. The Outer Limits or The Twilight Zone etc.?

Tags: filming

Can I do a documentary with the actors from The Outer Limits or The Twilight Zone etc.?

Is it possible or the actors cannot speak because of some waivers with the film studios?

Or I can ask the main characters, directors, producers without any problem and I need only the approval of the people I am questioning in the document?

I wont use any footage from the series just interviews with the actors,directors and other peopl who were involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IANAL but that would likely depend on their contracts with the studios.